# DOCX to PDF conversion loses hyperlinks on Mac OS X

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, docx, office-for-mac, microsoft-office-2008

I have a DOCX file that I'm trying to export from Word to PDF, but any way I try this, the hyperlinks stop working. Both the native PDF "Save As.." option and Print → "Save as Adobe PDF..." that comes with Acrobat Pro, all lose hyperlinks.

How can go around this?

PS: Using OpenOffice hyperlinks work fine, but several other parts of my DOCX get screwed, so I don't want to use it.

Answer (score 2):

The thread [Links Lost on Conversion to PDF](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/35881796/links-lost-on-conversion-to-pdf.aspx) offers the following solution :

> Open the word document in Pages and
>   then export to pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the Ms 2007 or later, if so you just open you file in it. Then office symble>scroll down to "save as" >PDF/XPS

Maybe you choose print and trigger the virtual printer-Acrobat Pro

It's nonsense that the hyperlinks will gone I need to notice you the http links rather than hyperlinks can easily be perserved!

Or maybe there is something wrong with

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not a concrete answer, but it seems from reading through [this thread](http://www.mackb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/word/14598/Links-Lost-on-Conversion-to-PDF) and others that there is an issue with hyperlinks being lost when converting Word documents to PDF on Office for Mac - exactly the behaviour you are seeing.